# How do I know if my 2008 Hyundai Sonata has the Premium Sound option?

Tags: hyundai, audio, sonata

I've read all over the place while trying to install an aftermarket stereo into my 2008 Hyundai Sonata GLS that there's a "premium sound" option that requires a special wiring harness. I bought this wiring harness without thinking about it. If I have premium sound, I will need to buy an extra adapter, and if I don't I will need to cut down this harness and remove some transistors.

How do I know for sure whether or not I have this "premium sound" option?

Comment: I would take the VIN to your local (or call) Hyundai dealer and have them tell you. They should have all the options installed on your car on their computers.

Comment: @Paulster2 : As your comment is a valid answer, I suggest you post it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bought the car and have the window sticker, all of the options will be listed on the sticker. If you don't have your window sticker anymore (usually only stupidly anal people like me would keep it), take your VIN down to your Hyundai dealership and ask them to see what options came on it. They should store all of that stuff in their databases (most manufacturers do this).